# Where can I find custom maps for Super Laser Racer?

Tags: super-laser-racer

I got [Super Laser Racer](http://www.newstargames.com/slr.html) from Steam, and it's pretty fun! It's getting pretty stale, though, with only 12 pre-made maps. There is a level-editor included, so I assume it is possible to download custom maps somewhere. Where can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought the game during the Steam Summer Perils Sale. I've played it once or twice (and I suck at it) but it's a lot of fun. I saw the level editor as well; you can save maps in your `My Documents\Super Laser Racer\Tracks` folder. There are also some custom maps on this forum: http://www.newstargames.com/newstarforum/forumdisplay.php?f=108

There are also mods available and they go under your `Steam\steamapps\common\super laser racer` folder